High Resolution Display Reverts to poor Quality on Login and Top Bar in Ubuntu 20.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my MSI Modern 15. Upon starting the system and reaching the login screen, the display resolution is noticeably low, around 1000x800. Once logged in, the resolution improves for the main desktop, but the top bar remains blur at the login screen.
Adjusting the display scaling settings temporarily resolves the issue until the next reboot. I have attempted to configure the GRUB settings by adding:
GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

However, this modification has not fixed the problem. I'm using Nvidia Drivers 450.57. Additionally, during login, the system displays MSI logo, which stays on the screen until the desktop is fully loaded.
What steps can I take to permanently correct the display resolution for both the login screen and the top bar?
